# ProgrammingError: Cursor closed while using Django ORM raw

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, mysql-python

There is a a repeating error

```
ProgrammingError: Cursor closed
```

when using a raw query using Django ORM

```
MyModel.objects.raw(<raw_sql_query>)
```

The database being used is MySQL, and the cursor object is not being accessed in any application code. All references found online refer to problems when dealing with the cursor object.
There are other instances of error:

```
Programming Error (2014, Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now)
```

in some celery tasks, which are running on separate hosts.

Can anyone help me with clues to debug this problem ? Or any areas I might have not explored which is leading to this error.

> Environment: Python 3.6+,  Django 2+,  Mysql 5.7+

Comment: If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order. This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result() - From the documentations.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow, I am not using methods exposed by MySQLDb in my application layer. I am using Django's ORM methods. So, mysql_use_result() is not present anywhere in my application code.